# create a multidimensional python list in a loop

Tags: python, list

I try to create a multidimensional array in python 3.7. Unfortunately I do not know the variable type, the dimensions or the amount of dimensions beforehand. My approach so far is a loop:

```
dimensions = [3,3]
vartype = 'binary'

if vartype=='binary':
    new_array=False
elif vartype=='int':
    new_array=0

for dim in dimensions:
    new_array = [new_array for _ in range(dim)]
```

The issue is, that if there is more than 1 dimension I end up with multiple references to the first dimension:

```
new_array[0][1]=True
print(new_array)

[[False, True, False], 
 [False, True, False],   
 [False, True, False]]
```

This has been addressed quite some times like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly). In other cases however the amount of dimensions is known, so I can't transfer the solution to my problem.
Does anyone know a way to create arrays of varying amount of dimensions?

Comment: If native python is not a requirement, `numpy` is your solution.

Comment: native is preferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fact that the constructors for `bool` and `int` return the default values for those data types when invoked without an argument, i.e. `bool() is False` and `int() == 0`.

To make things generic for any number of dimensions, you could use a bit of clever recursion...

```py
def make_array(dimension, element_ctor):
    return [element_ctor() for x in range(dimension)]


def make_ndim_array(dimensions, element_ctor):
    return make_array(
        dimensions[0],
        (
            element_ctor
            if len(dimensions) == 1
            else lambda: make_ndim_array(dimensions[1:], element_ctor)
        ),
    )


print(make_ndim_array([2, 3, 4], int))
print(make_ndim_array([3, 3], str))
```

outputs

```py
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
[['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
```

Since `element_ctor` can be any function that can be invoked without an argument, you can even use this for an n-dimensional array of random numbers...

```
import random
print(make_ndim_array([2, 4, 11], random.random))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy

for dim in dimensions:
    new_array = [copy.deepcopy(new_array) for _ in range(dim)]
```